# Data read from the file, but a core dumped error occurs

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


class C{
    private:
        int work_loc, floor_no;
    public:
        C(){}
        void printC(){
            std::cout << "work Location: " << work_loc << "  floor_no: " << floor_no;
        }
        C(int work_loc1, int floor_no1): work_loc(work_loc1), floor_no(floor_no1){}
};

class B{
    private:
        int empid_;
        std::string name_;
        C obj_c;
    public:
        B(int empid, std::string name, int work_loc, int floor_no): empid_(empid), name_(name){
            obj_c = C(work_loc, floor_no);
        }
        void printB(){
            std::cout << empid_ << " " << name_ << "\n ";
            obj_c.printC(); 

        }


};

class A{
private:
    std::vector<B> calls;
public:
    void addToCalls(B b){
        calls.push_back(b);
    }
    void printAll(){

        for(size_t i = 0; static_cast<int>(i) < 3; i++){
            std::cout << "i is " << i << "\n";
           calls[i].printB(); 
        }

    }
    int callSize(){
        return calls.size();
    }


};


int main(){
    A a, c;

    a.addToCalls(B(1,"a1", 1, 33));
    a.addToCalls(B(2,"b2", 3 ,44));
    a.addToCalls(B(3,"c2", 4, 55));
    a.addToCalls(B(4,"d3", 5, 22));
    a.addToCalls(B(5,"e4", 3, 88));
    a.printAll();
    std::cout << "end of a\n";  
    // FILE* f;
    // FILE* f1;
    // f = std::fopen("serial.txt", "w+");
    std::cout << "begin another a \n  ";
    std::fstream  f;
    std::fstream  f2;
    f.open("class_data.txt", std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
    f.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));

    // fwrite(a, sizeof(a), sizeof(a), f);
    // fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    f.close();
    // rewind(f);
    // f.open("class_data.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    f2.open("class_data.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    f2.read((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
    std::cout << "the size of C is " << c.callSize() << "\n"; 
    c.printAll();
    // f.close();
    f2.close();


}
```

Here I get the data gets copied into the object c, but it gives out an error.
After the values are printed, the code gives the core dumped error.
The value of the object is copied from the file, which is also written at the same time. Is it because of the 2 file pointers opening the same file?
Here's the backtrace

```
i is 0
1 a1
 work Location: 1  floor_no: 33i is 1
2 b2
 work Location: 3  floor_no: 44i is 2
3 c2
 work Location: 4  floor_no: 55end of a
begin another a 
  the size of C is 5
i is 0
1 a1
 work Location: 1  floor_no: 33i is 1
2 b2
 work Location: 3  floor_no: 44i is 2
3 c2
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000135fda0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fae6020e7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7fae6021737a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fae6021b53c]
./a.out[0x4028ea]
./a.out[0x40276a]
./a.out[0x402564]
./a.out[0x4021e3]
./a.out[0x401c80]
./a.out[0x401ad6]
./a.out[0x401635]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fae601b7830]
./a.out[0x4010c9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 fc:02 17574813                           /home/local/Serialisation/a.out
00603000-00604000 r--p 00003000 fc:02 17574813                           /home/local/Serialisation/a.out
00604000-00605000 rw-p 00004000 fc:02 17574813                           /home/local/Serialisation/a.out
0134e000-01380000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fae58000000-7fae58021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fae58021000-7fae5c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fae5fe8e000-7fae5ff96000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1573048                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fae5ff96000-7fae60195000 ---p 00108000 fc:00 1573048                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fae60195000-7fae60196000 r--p 00107000 fc:00 1573048                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fae60196000-7fae60197000 rw-p 00108000 fc:00 1573048                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fae60197000-7fae60357000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1573053                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fae60357000-7fae60557000 ---p 001c0000 fc:00 1573053                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fae60557000-7fae6055b000 r--p 001c0000 fc:00 1573053                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fae6055b000-7fae6055d000 rw-p 001c4000 fc:00 1573053                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fae6055d000-7fae60561000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fae60561000-7fae60577000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1573314                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fae60577000-7fae60776000 ---p 00016000 fc:00 1573314                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fae60776000-7fae60777000 rw-p 00015000 fc:00 1573314                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fae60777000-7fae608e9000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 4718942                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fae608e9000-7fae60ae9000 ---p 00172000 fc:00 4718942                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fae60ae9000-7fae60af3000 r--p 00172000 fc:00 4718942                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fae60af3000-7fae60af5000 rw-p 0017c000 fc:00 4718942                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fae60af5000-7fae60af9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fae60af9000-7fae60b1f000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1573031                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fae60cf9000-7fae60cfe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fae60d1b000-7fae60d1e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fae60d1e000-7fae60d1f000 r--p 00025000 fc:00 1573031                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fae60d1f000-7fae60d20000 rw-p 00026000 fc:00 1573031                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fae60d20000-7fae60d21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd8c65f000-7ffd8c681000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd8c7a7000-7ffd8c7a9000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd8c7a9000-7ffd8c7ab000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
 work Location: 4  floor_no: 55Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to add the complete output plz ? I don't understand where your code crashes.

Comment: Edited my output.

Comment: have a look @PlikPlok

Comment: I was on board with Max's answer but seeing the error message `*** Error in './a.out': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000135fda0 ***` and that `c.printAll()` seems to at least print the list (then crash).
I would suggest using stream operators anyway (`<<` `>>`), the std::vector implementation has pointers in it and maybe the destruction of both vectors' internal components cause your error. Stream operators should construct two separate vectors, copies of one another.

Comment: @PlikPlok how did it read the data from the file? Since the serialization was not proper here.

Comment: As Max pointed out, if the vector goes out of scope and is destroyed between the read and write operations, what you will read will be the internal data structure of a vector but one that has been deleted and therefore is invalid. Try to read and write on separate little programs and you'll see it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

Your class `A` has a member of type `std::vector`. You can't just write an `std::vector` as binary data into a file and expect to be able to read it back.

You need to write and read each member of the `std::vector`.

The same goes for `std::string` in `B`, you can't simply write the `std::string` object, you need to write the underlying `data`, and then when reading the data construct a new `std::string` from it.

You can define your own `<<` and `>>` operators for your classes, and use them with your stream, like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const A& a) 
{
    // Write data from a to stream
    return stream;
}

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& stream, A& a)  
{  
    // Read data from stream to a
    return stream;
}
```

Then instead of `f.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));` you simply do `f << a;`

Comment: Looks like it works in this particular case since the "vector's raw byte data" is immediately read from the file without anything being destroyed between the write command and read command. You response is completely valid though and stream operators are the way to go.

Comment: Well, "works", until both vectors go out of scope, and free the same memory. One of the many things that can (and will) go wrong when writing and reading such types directly as binary data.

Answer (score 1):

Class `A` is not a [trivially copyable type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable), so it will NOT work to pretend it is just a sequence of bytes.

You will need to look into "serialization" to properly convert your objects to and from binary files.